# source code shows proper img tag from $row output, but no actual image in browser

Tags: 7, views, theming

In my tpl file that has custom code for a block view, I have an object $perfomer which I use to display it's picture with custom code. So I've written code as follows:

```
    <?php $picture = file_load($performer->field_performer_foto['und'][0]['fid']);  ?>
    <?php $realpicture = file_create_url($picture->uri); ?>
 <?php  print '<img scr="' . $realpicture . '" alt="'.$title.'" width="120" height=120/>'; ?>
```

So like the title of my question says, in my source code I get a proper img tag that looks like this:

```
<img scr="http://www.breinwijzer.be/festidev12345/sites/default/files/Santens_Patrick.jpg" alt="Patrick Santens" width="120" height=120/>
```

To test this, I pasted this html into a Page, and the picture showed just fine on that page. However, in the block view for which the mentioned `tpl` file is coded, there is no picture shown in the browser, only a square box of `120px` by `120px` with the `alt` value inside of it.

Comment: `<img scr` should be `<img src` :)

Comment: Absolutely. How it didn't cross my mind as my page tolerated this ouch. Why don't you put it in an answer so I can mark it. Solved!

Answer (score 1):

Ok creds to clive. See syntax error in comments.

For those who need the actual code in the answer: 
`<img scr` should be `<img src` :)

Comment: I answered my own question and it does answer it. There is no critique and everythings pretty clear to me. I'll put the actual syntax I referred to in the answer if that makes you feel better.

Comment: Oops ! My mistake... Didn't see the author while reviewing it... Makes sense :-)